# Get total waiting time and number of rows from date intervals

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below given schema and data, we need to find the time waited for each vehicle and number of stops.

```
     --- CREATE TABLE
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_Detail](
        [Sno] [int] NOT NULL,
        [VehicleId] [nchar](10) NULL,
        [DriverId] [nchar](10) NULL,
        [LocationId] [nchar](10) NULL,
        [StartTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
        [EndTime] [datetime2](7) NULL
        )

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_Main](
        [Sno] [int] NOT NULL,
        [VehicleId] [nchar](10) NULL,
        [StartTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
        [EndTime] [datetime2](7) NULL) 

         -- INSERT DATA

    INSERT [dbo].[Table_Main] ([Sno], [VehicleId], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (1, N'1001      ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T07:25:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T17:25:33.0000000' AS DateTime2))
    INSERT [dbo].[Table_Main] ([Sno], [VehicleId], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (2, N'1002      ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T06:12:52.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T11:21:35.0000000' AS DateTime2))



    INSERT [dbo].[Table_Detail] ([Sno], [VehicleId], [DriverId], [LocationId], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (1, N'1001      ', N'34        ', N'53        ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T07:55:32.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T08:15:23.0000000' AS DateTime2))
    INSERT [dbo].[Table_Detail] ([Sno], [VehicleId], [DriverId], [LocationId], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (2, N'1002      ', N'23        ', N'65        ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T07:11:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T07:45:33.0000000' AS DateTime2))
    INSERT [dbo].[Table_Detail] ([Sno], [VehicleId], [DriverId], [LocationId], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (3, N'1001      ', N'34        ', N'53        ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T09:22:52.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T09:45:59.0000000' AS DateTime2))
    INSERT [dbo].[Table_Detail] ([Sno], [VehicleId], [DriverId], [LocationId], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (4, N'1002      ', N'23        ', N'65        ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T10:25:13.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T11:15:23.0000000' AS DateTime2))
    INSERT [dbo].[Table_Detail] ([Sno], [VehicleId], [DriverId], [LocationId], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (5, N'1001      ', N'34        ', N'53        ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T11:25:36.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T12:35:37.0000000' AS DateTime2))
    INSERT [dbo].[Table_Detail] ([Sno], [VehicleId], [DriverId], [LocationId], [StartTime], [EndTime]) VALUES (6, N'1001      ', N'34        ', N'53        ', CAST(N'2019-02-15T15:15:33.0000000' AS DateTime2), CAST(N'2019-02-15T15:25:21.0000000' AS DateTime2))
```

My expected result is

[Sno], [VehicleId], [StartTime], [EndTime] , [Total Time waited], [ no of records]

```
 StartTime  EndTime
2019-02-15 07:55:32.0000000 2019-02-15 08:15:23.0000000 =   00:20:10
2019-02-15 09:22:52.0000000 2019-02-15 09:45:59.0000000 =   00:23:08
2019-02-15 11:25:36.0000000 2019-02-15 12:35:37.0000000 =   01:10:01
2019-02-15 15:15:33.0000000 2019-02-15 15:25:21.0000000 =   00:10:14

Total Time : 02:03:20
No of Records :4
```

ie :Total time waited for vehicle 1 is 
Total Time : 02:03:20
No of Records :4

this way i need SQL Query for all the vehicles

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try following which is fully tested.  I modeled the classes :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DBO dbo = new DBO() {
                Table_Main = new List<Table_Main>() {
                    new Table_Main() { Sno = 1, VehicleId = "1001      ", StartTime = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-15T07:25:33.0000000"), EndTime = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-15T17:25:33.0000000")},
                    new Table_Main() { Sno = 2, VehicleId = "1002      ", StartTime = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-15T06:12:52.0000000"), EndTime = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-15T11:21:35.0000000")}
                },
                Table_Detail = new List<Table_Detail>() {
                    new Table_Detail() { Sno = 1, VehicleId = "1001      ", DriverId =  "34        ", LocationId = "53        ", StartTime = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-15T07:55:32.0000000"), EndTime = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-15T08:15:23.0000000")},
                    new Table_Detail() { Sno = 2, VehicleId = "1002      ", DriverId =  "23        ", LocationId = "65        ", StartTime = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-15T07:11:33.0000000"), EndTime = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-15T07:45:33.0000000")},
                    new Table_Detail() { Sno = 3, VehicleId = "1001      ", DriverId =  "34        ", LocationId = "53        ", StartTime = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-15T09:22:52.0000000"), EndTime = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-15T09:45:59.0000000")},
                    new Table_Detail() { Sno = 4, VehicleId = "1002      ", DriverId =  "23        ", LocationId = "65        ", StartTime = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-15T10:25:13.0000000"), EndTime = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-15T11:15:23.0000000")},
                    new Table_Detail() { Sno = 5, VehicleId = "1001      ", DriverId =  "34        ", LocationId = "53        ", StartTime = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-15T11:25:36.0000000"), EndTime = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-15T12:35:37.0000000")},
                    new Table_Detail() { Sno = 6, VehicleId = "1001      ", DriverId =  "34        ", LocationId = "53        ", StartTime = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-15T15:15:33.0000000"), EndTime = DateTime.Parse("2019-02-15T15:25:21.0000000")}
                }
            };

            var groups = dbo.Table_Detail.OrderBy(x => x.StartTime).GroupBy(x => new { VehicleId = x.VehicleId.Trim(), DriverId = x.DriverId.Trim() }).ToList();

            var results = groups.Select(x => new {Times = x.Select(y => new { Sno = y.Sno, VehicleId = y.VehicleId, StartTime = y.StartTime, EndTime = y.EndTime}).ToList(), Waited = new TimeSpan(0,0,x.Sum(y => (y.EndTime - y.StartTime).Seconds) ), Count = x.Count() }).ToList(); 

        }
    }

    public class DBO
    {
        public List<Table_Detail> Table_Detail { get; set; }
        public List<Table_Main> Table_Main { get; set; }

    }
    public class Table_Detail
    {
        public int Sno { get; set;}
        public string VehicleId { get; set;}
        public string DriverId { get; set; }
        public string LocationId { get; set;}
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set;}
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set;}
    }
    public class Table_Main
    {
        public int Sno { get;set; }
        public string VehicleId { get;set;}
        public DateTime StartTime { get; set;}
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set;}

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i am looking for SQL Code

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT
    VehicleId = T.VehicleId,
    ElapsedTime = CONVERT(
        VARCHAR(50), 
        DATEADD(
            MILLISECOND, 
            SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, T.StartTime, T.EndTime)) * 1000, 
            0), 
        114),
    NoOfRecords = COUNT(1)
FROM
    [dbo].[Table_Detail] AS T
GROUP BY
    T.VehicleId
```

Results:

```
VehicleId   ElapsedTime     NoOfRecords
1001        02:02:47:000    4
1002        01:24:10:000    2
```

`DATEDIFF(SECOND, T.StartTime, T.EndTime)` returns the amount of seconds between each interval. `SUM()` just adds all these seconds for a particular vehicle (from the `GROUP BY` column list).

The `DATEADD(MILLISECOND, <seconds> * 1000, 0)` is used to convert the sum of total seconds to a `DATETIME` value and then the `CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), <datetime>, 14)` is used to display this datetime value as time.

Comment: Super, but given a vehicle is entered multiple times, i need to consider each entry time as separate based on main table

Comment: In that case you can join both tables together by vehicle ID and period overlap (`A.StartDate <= B.EndDate AND B.EndDate >= A.StartDate`).

Comment: I am posting my query below in answer.. kinldy give the query

Comment: kindly let me know for my below values inserted with query